# What happens when you rsync without a destination path?

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy

I copied a file to destination without providing the path. It seems to have copied successfully, but i cant find the file in the destination, where could it be located?

```
rsync -av --progress file.txt user@host
sending incremental file list
file.txt
  1048576000 100%   63.19MB/s    0:00:15 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)
```

Answer (score 14):

You now have a file in your working directory called "`user@host`". If you had copied it to a remote location without a path, `user@host:` (note colon) would have called it `file.txt` in whatever the default location on that server is (likely `user`'s home directory).